# PATH setting. Updating TLMGR via Terminal

Tags: paths

I'm trying to update tlmgr via Terminal using the .sh file `update-tlmgr-latest.sh`. When I hit the enter button i get this error:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater......................................................................................................................................................................................
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
[omurcia@dhcppc1 ~]$ sh /home/omurcia/update-tlmgr-latest.sh 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater......................................................................................................................................................................................
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
```

I don't know how to proceed in this case. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Any particular reason you don't want to do `tlmgr update --self`?

Comment: What does `kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT` give? If you get an error, what does `echo $PATH` give? I'm assuming you are on OS X.

Comment: There is a bug which causes this if you use the TeX Live Utility to update, but you can avoid it by using the command line. So I'm not clear what exactly you've tried or what's happening. But `tlmgr update --self` is known to work around the problem, so I suggest trying that.

Comment: See my comment [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219499/kpsewhich-command-not-found-on-tlmgr-update-mactex-install#comment515263_219499). A bug report has been filed. In the meantime you can update with `sudo tlmgr update --self`, as @cfr suggests.

Comment: @cfr As far as I know, this is not a bug in TeX Live Utility, and I suspect it's not limited to Mac OS X. The http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh script should work for any UNIX system, but it appears to be broken. The problem has been reported to the TeX Live team.

Comment: I'm going to try some of these solutions. I'm in Fedora 21.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell Ah. I only guessed OS X because the OP talked about 'Terminal'.

Comment: According to Norbert Preining, the problem with `update-tlmgr-latest.sh` is now fixed.