# kpsewhich: command not found. on tlmgr update, MacTex install

Tags: texlive, installing, paths

I tried to update the tlmgr with TexLive-Utility and it fails to find kpsewhich.  I'm not sure why though, because it is in my bash PATH

```
$which kpsewhich
/usr/texbin/kpsewhich
```

Not only that, it is in the PATH that TeXLive-Utility creates for its own environment, but then the log file shows two different PATH variables...  Here is the log (with some personal info redacted)

```
2014-12-26 02:38:24 +0000 Notice -[TLMAppController _checkSystemPythonVersion][3465]    Using Python interpreter at '/usr/bin/python'
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
2014-12-26 02:38:24 +0000 Notice -[TLMAppController _checkProcessUmask][3465]   Process umask = 022
2014-12-26 02:38:24 +0000 Notice -[TLMAppController applicationDidFinishLaunching:][3465]   Welcome to TeX Live Utility 1.17, running under Mac OS X Version 10.10.1 (Build 14B25) with 4/4 processors active and 8.0 GB physical memory.
2014-12-26 02:38:24 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment updateEnvironment][3465]  Setting up a new environment for /usr/local/texlive/2014…
2014-12-26 02:38:24 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment updatePathEnvironment][3465]  Using PATH = "(
    "/usr/local/bin",
    "/usr/bin",
    "/bin",
    "/usr/sbin",
    "/sbin",
    "/usr/texbin"
)"
2014-12-26 02:38:24 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment updatePathEnvironment][3465]  /usr/bin/env
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/texbin
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.EwTEw7Hhie/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
DBUS_LAUNCHD_SESSION_BUS_SOCKET=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Mg3IUoeulu/unix_domain_listener
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.pyOdcu5mIa/Listeners
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.UmmBWlY0EC/Render
SHELL=/bin/bash
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
TMPDIR=/var/folders/bh/xqbvhy9j1hg21kb0bh_mm8jc0000gn/T/
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.EwTEw7Hhie/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
DBUS_LAUNCHD_SESSION_BUS_SOCKET=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Mg3IUoeulu/unix_domain_listener
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.pyOdcu5mIa/Listeners
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.UmmBWlY0EC/Render
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/bh/xqbvhy9j1hg21kb0bh_mm8jc0000gn/T/

2014-12-26 02:38:25 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment _getInstalledYear:isDevelopmentVersion:tlmgrVersion:][3465]   Looks like you're using TeX Live 2014
2014-12-26 02:38:25 +0000 Notice -[TLMEnvironment _checkForRootPrivileges][3465]    Root permission required for installation at /usr/local/texlive/2014
2014-12-26 02:38:25 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment updateEnvironment][3465]  Nothing to update for /usr/local/texlive/2014
2014-12-26 02:38:25 +0000 Notice -[TLMLogWindowController awakeFromNib][3465]   Loaded log window controller
2014-12-26 02:38:25 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase _downloadDatabaseHead][3465] Checking the repository version.  Please be patient.
2014-12-26 02:38:25 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase _downloadDatabaseHead][3465] Downloading at least 2048 bytes of tlpdb for a version check…
2014-12-26 02:38:26 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:][3465]  redirected request to http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
2014-12-26 02:38:26 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase _downloadDatabaseHead][3465] Downloaded 130749 bytes of tlpdb for version check
2014-12-26 02:38:27 +0000 Notice -[TLMEnvironment _getValidServerURL:repositoryYear:][3465] Repository version appears to be 2014; a young TeX Live
2014-12-26 02:38:27 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _refreshLocalDatabase][3465] Updating local package database
2014-12-26 02:38:27 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _refreshUpdatedPackageListFromLocation:][3465]   Refreshing list of updated packages…
2014-12-26 02:38:34 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _paperSizeCheckTerminated:][3465]    System paper size = a4, pdftex paper size = (null)
2014-12-26 02:38:39 +0000 Notice -[TLMOperation main][3465] Successfully executed `/usr/texbin/tlmgr --machine-readable --repository http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/ update --list --all`
2014-12-26 02:38:39 +0000 Notice -[TLMOperation main][3465] tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/
===============================================================================
tlmgr itself needs to be updated.
Please do this via either
  tlmgr update --self
or by getting the latest updater for Unix-ish systems:
  http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
and/or Windows systems:
  http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.exe
Then continue with other updates as usual.
===============================================================================
2014-12-26 02:38:42 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _handleListUpdatesFinishedNotification:][3465]   Critical updates detected: (
    "texlive.infra"
)
2014-12-26 02:39:01 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _isCorrectDatabaseVersionAtURL:][3465]   Checking database version in case preferences have been changed…
2014-12-26 02:39:01 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _updateAllPackagesFromRepository:][3465] Beginning infrastructure update from http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/
2014-12-26 02:39:01 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation _synchronouslyDownloadURL:toPath:][3465] Downloading URL: http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
2014-12-26 02:39:01 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:][3465]    Download redirected to http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh, expecting 0 bytes.
2014-12-26 02:39:02 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveResponse:][3465]  Will download 4794067 bytes…
2014-12-26 02:39:04 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveDataOfLength:][3465]  Received 20% of 4794067 bytes…
2014-12-26 02:39:05 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveDataOfLength:][3465]  Received 41% of 4794067 bytes…
2014-12-26 02:39:06 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveDataOfLength:][3465]  Received 63% of 4794067 bytes…
2014-12-26 02:39:07 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveDataOfLength:][3465]  Received 85% of 4794067 bytes…
2014-12-26 02:39:08 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation downloadDidFinish:][3465]    Download of 4794067 bytes complete
2014-12-26 02:39:08 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation _downloadUpdateScript][3465] First line of downloaded file is: "#!/bin/sh"…good!
2014-12-26 02:39:08 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation _synchronouslyDownloadURL:toPath:][3465] Downloading URL: http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh.sha256
2014-12-26 02:39:08 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:][3465]    Download redirected to http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh.sha256, expecting 0 bytes.
2014-12-26 02:39:08 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveResponse:][3465]  Will download 89 bytes…
2014-12-26 02:39:08 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveDataOfLength:][3465]  Received 100% of 89 bytes…
2014-12-26 02:39:08 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation downloadDidFinish:][3465]    Download of 89 bytes complete
2014-12-26 02:39:08 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation _downloadAndCheckHash][3465] SHA256 signature looks okay
2014-12-26 02:39:08 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][3465]   Checking code signature before running tlu_ipctask as root…
2014-12-26 02:39:08 +0000 Notice /usr/bin/codesign[3465]    /Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/tlu_ipctask: valid on disk
/Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/tlu_ipctask: satisfies its Designated Requirement
2014-12-26 02:39:08 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][3465]   Signature was valid, okay to run tlu_ipctask
2014-12-26 02:39:14 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][3465]   Invoking privileged task via AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges
2014-12-26 02:39:14 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3664]  dropped privileges to user nobody
2014-12-26 02:39:15 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation setWrapperPID:][3465] tlu_ipctask checking in:  tlu_ipctask pid = 3664
2014-12-26 02:39:16 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation setUnderlyingPID:][3465]  tlu_ipctask checking in: pid = 3665 (/var/folders/bh/xqbvhy9j1hg21kb0bh_mm8jc0000gn/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.LUkU1n/update-tlmgr-latest.sh --nox11)
2014-12-26 02:39:16 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3664]  tlu_ipctask: child HOME = '/var/root'
2014-12-26 02:39:16 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3664]  tlu_ipctask: current HOME = '/var/empty'
2014-12-26 02:39:16 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3664]  Verifying archive integrity... All good.
2014-12-26 02:39:16 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3664]  Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater......................................................................................................................................................................................
```

But the main problem occurs when the install script "runme.sh" begins.

```
2014-12-26 02:39:16 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3664] ./runme.sh: line 11: kpsewhich: command not found
2014-12-26 02:39:16 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3664] ./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
2014-12-26 02:39:16 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3664] ./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
2014-12-26 02:39:16 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][3465] kqueue noted that pid 3665 exited (/var/folders/bh/xqbvhy9j1hg21kb0bh_mm8jc0000gn/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.LUkU1n/update-tlmgr-latest.sh --nox11)
2014-12-26 02:39:16 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3664]  child process pid = 3665 exited
2014-12-26 02:39:17 +0000 Error tlu_ipctask[3664]   Value of errno is No such file or directory
2014-12-26 02:39:17 +0000 Error tlu_ipctask[3664]   *** ERROR *** exit status of pid = 3665 was 1
2014-12-26 02:39:17 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][3465] waitpid returned 3664, WIFEXITED(256) = 1, errno = 93 (Attribute not found)
2014-12-26 02:39:17 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][3465] kqueue noted that tlu_ipctask (pid = 3664) exited with status 1
2014-12-26 02:39:18 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation main][3465]  Removed temp directory "/var/folders/bh/xqbvhy9j1hg21kb0bh_mm8jc0000gn/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.LUkU1n"
```

The question is:  what PATH variable does TexLive-Utility use here (note that it is listed twice in the environment), and how can I "set it" like TeXLive-Utility recommends, when it makes up its own environment anyway?

Comment: A [bug report](https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/issues/11) has been filed. There was also a bit of discussion of this [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=19251095#19251095). In the meantime, you can update the infrastructure with `sudo tlmgr update --self`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug that has now been fixed.

Comment: @AdamLiter Not sure if this has been fixed. I just installed BasicTex on OSX 10.10 and got the very same error. The answer below solved my problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should be a transient problem, and it has been reported to TeX Live upstream. TeX Live Utility uses [update-tlmgr-latest.sh](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh) to perform the update, because of historical problems with `tlmgr update --self`.

As TLU maintainer, I recommend that users just wait until it's fixed on the server, but you can run the update command in Terminal if you're desperate for some package update.

**Edit: According to the TeX Live team, this is now fixed. The fixed version should be on all CTAN mirrors by now.**

You may be able to work around the problem by choosing the Action menu while holding down the Option key, and selecting the item "Install TeX Live Manager From Critical Repository." Some users report download failures with this method.

Should this question be marked as off-topic, now? Presumably someone with a higher score than I can do that…

Comment: Just to update this, the fix hasn't actually gone out to the CTAN mirrors yet. I'm still having the same issue.

According to the author of the above answer (or so I assume, same name), on 12/28 "the fix hasn't been pushed to CTAN yet. Wait a few days." You can see this response in context here: [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.macosx/46659)

Comment: @AmishChipmunk Sigh, yes. Updated accordingly. I'm tracking this damn problem on 3 mailing lists, here, and my TLU bug report page.

Comment: Has the fixed been pushed to CTAN yet?

Comment: @LongOuyang Yes, `update-tlmgr-latest.sh` is fixed on CTAN as of a couple of weeks ago. It should be on all mirrors by now.