# TeXstudio PATH problem with kpsewhich

Tags: texlive, texstudio, paths

If I start up TeXstudio by launching it normally as an app in OS X Yosemite, whenever I build and view a document, it complains `kpsewhich: command not found`.

However, `which kpsewhich` in a terminal shows it exists at `/Library/TeX/texbin/kpsewhich`. And `echo $PATH` includes `/Library/TeX/texbin`. *So if I start up TeXstudio from the terminal the problem disappears*.

I wonder if there is PATH configuration problem somewhere for TeXstudio such that it does not load `/Library/TeX/texbin` properly. If so, how do I fix it?

Note: my problem initially led me to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219499/kpsewhich-command-not-found-on-tlmgr-update-mactex-install), but I have installed the latest `MacTex` and updated all my packages using TexLive, so it should be safe to say the cause of my problem is different.

Comment: Can you not configure paths in the settings for the editor? I'd assume that might be necessary. I have not used MacTeX for ages, but it used to use `/usr/texbin`. (This was a symbolic link to the directory in `/Library` but `/Library` would not typically have been in `PATH`.) However, I know Apple is locking out users from `/usr` so maybe this has changed to workaround that problem.

Comment: Certainly in earlier versions of OS X, GUI applications did ***not*** typically inherit `PATH`, and getting them to do that was a complete headache. However, I thought they had done away with at least some of the craziness of the system.

Comment: MacTeX 2014 installs links at `/usr/texbin` and `/Library/TeX/texbin` as future-proofing against the next release of OS X, which will wipe out `/usr/texbin` for good. Yosemite did have an [environment bug](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208181/why-did-my-tex-related-gui-program-stop-working-in-mac-os-x-yosemite) that would cause problems like this, but it should be fixed as of 10.10.4 or so. How do your paths compare to this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38627/commands-paths-in-texstudio-on-mac-os-x-with-could-not-start-the-command-err

Comment: @cfr, yes, the `/usr/texbin` stuff are all symbolic links, but the question is which setting(s) in TeXstudio I should adjust to fix the problem.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell, I'm running 10.10.5, and I've compared my settings in the question you referenced, they are the same. But the problem persists.

Comment: Do you know how exactly the PATH is set on your Mac? For Linux users this usually comes when people manually set path in bashrc, then things does not work in editors started from a menu. Also exactly what is listed in the TS  command config for say pdflatex?

Comment: @daleif, PATH is set via '~/.bash_profile` and I have little idea in terms of whether and how TeXstudio picks it up. For `pdflatex`, the command config is: `/usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Comment: This seems to mean that TS gas setup full paths instead of just noting the commands to be called.  What does `which pdflatex` say?

Comment: @MLister Do programs launched from the Finder read `.bash_profile`? I don't think they do.

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/texbin/pdflatex` give?

Comment: TeXstudio implicitly assumes that kpsewhich is in the same directory as latex. Try setting an absolute path to the latex command in `Options -> Commands`.

Comment: @daleif, `which pdflatex` gives `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`

Comment: @cfr, `ls -l /usr/texbin/pdflatex` gives `/usr/texbin/pdflatex -> pdftex`

Comment: @doed, do you mean the `Commands ($PATH)` field under `Additional Search Paths` section? At the moment it shows `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin`

Comment: Are you really using TeX Live from 2012? Change that path under `Additional Search Paths` to `/usr/texbin`. `ls -l /usr/texbin/pdftex` should point to something under `/Library`. The stuff under `/Library` should include symbolic links to `/usr/local/texlive`.

Comment: @cfr, this is very strange. I just looked up `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin`, but it didn't even exist, instead, there is `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin`, which made me think that TeXstudio hardcodes some of these paths and ignore it if not available and try to look elsewhere automatically.